# JQuery: failure to identity elements in parsed HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am making a node application that needs to identify specific elements from a web request. I am able to download the raw string from the request but when I try to find an element from the parsed html it returns '.whateverelement is not a function'.

```
var coolElements = [];
request('https://google.com', (error, response, htmlString) => {   
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var html = $.parseHTML(htmlString);

        html.find('.whateverelement').each(function(i) {
            coolElements.append($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Take a look at Cheerio, I think you might be using code related to it but you're not importing it.

Comment: Oh wait if this is frontend code then what I said is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from jQuery documentation:

**jQuery.parseHTML()**
Description: Parses a string into an array of DOM nodes.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

It returns an array and you're trying to find elements inside that array based on query selectors: `html.find('.whateverelement')`. It returns `.whateverelement` is not a function because the `find` method from an array takes a function as the parameter.

You probably want to use something like `var html = $(htmlString);`, which should return a jQuery element with the parsed HTML, however I advice taking a look at https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio if you want to run jQuery on the server-side (nodejs).

Good luck!